# regexp matching in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, redmine

I have the following string that needs to be replaced by an empty character in rails. Followed many tutorials and docs. Please help me achieve this.

String:

```
/home/<someword>/dbdumps/backup.sql
```

To be replaced as:

```
backup
```

Comment: Do you need to ensure that only paths starting in `/home/` and ending in `/dbdumps/` will be matched? With exactly one directory in-between? And is `backup` constant or variable?

Comment: aah, sorry. I dont even know if it is backup.sql. It is like this.

/home/<username>/dbdumps/<somename>.sql and i just want the somename out

Answer (score 1):

To get the file name from a path, I'd use [File#basename](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-basename)

```
File.basename('/home/<someword>/dbdumps/backup.sql', '.sql')   
#=> 'backup'
```

Answer (score 0):

if "someword" is the only thing that changes you dont even need regex. 
Assume

```
path = "/home/<someword>/dbdumps/backup.sql"
```

then

```
path.split("/").last.split(".").first
```

returns

```
=> "backup"
```

Comment: Actually, this will get the (extensionless) filename from *any* path, regardless of whether it starts with `/home/` or ends in `/dbdumps/` or how many directories it contains. So it's probably not what @Medhamsh intends to do...

Comment: In a rails app i do a Net:SSH:start( ) and run ssh.exec!('ls /home/*/dbdumps/*.sql'). I am sending the output to a string and then i have to display the list of the files. For that I am taking the output into a string and trying to do a gsub. Is this the right approach?

Comment: You should put that in the original question, makes it much more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Medhamsh check this out http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob

Comment: You are using ssh because your are fetching the files from remote systems, right? Otherwise there are better ways to access the FS as AJCodez has pointed out.

Comment: Yes, I am fetching the list from a remote machine

Comment: I made a seperate answer to draft this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be a gsub (string substitution) like so:

```
string = "home/<someword>/dbdumps/backup.sql"
new_string = string.gsub(%r{home/(.*)/dbdumps/backup.sql}, 'backup' )
```

This is a simple example of string substitution.

Answer (score 0):

> In a rails app i do a Net:SSH:start( ) and run ssh.exec!('ls /home/*/dbdumps/*.sql'). I am ?sending the output to a string and then i have to display the list of the files. For that I am taking the output into a string and trying to do a gsub. Is this the right approach?

I would not consider it pretty (naive code, no error checking, loops with requests) but something like this could do the job for you. It depends if you want to end up with just the backup names or the full path.

```
ssh.exec!("ls -l /home/") do |channel, stream, data|
  directories << data if stream == :stdout
end

directories.each do |dir|
  ssh.exec!("ls -l /home/" + dir + "dbdumps") do |channel, stream, data|
    backup_names << /home/" + dir + "/" + data if stream == :stdout
  end 
end
```

hope this helps